# Dlang: Construct an array from a pointer and length

Tags: arrays, pointers, d

I have a pointer and length. How to get a dynamic array from them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let `ptr` is a pointer and `len` is a length, then it is easy as the following:

```
ptr[0..len]
```

Note that this does not copy the array, but uses data in-place.

If you want to copy the array, use

```
ptr[0..len].dup
```

or

```
ptr[0..len].idup
```